# VBA: Calculation gone wrong #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've been tasked with creating a Value at Risk function that can reference data in a range and a couple of cells.  Code is:

```
Option Explicit
Function VaR(returns As Range, days, confidenceinterval, portfoliovalue)

VaR = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(returns) * Application.WorksheetFunction.SQRT(days)) - (Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(confidenceinterval) * (Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(returns) * Application.WorksheetFunction.SQRT(days))) * portfoliovalue

End Function
```

Returns is a range of returns, while the others are just values in cells.

As you can infer, i just copied my excel test formula, adding application.worksheet before each of the arguments.  However, whereas my test formula works, the identical code translated in a format the VBA should recognised, does not.

The original formula is

```
 =(AVERAGE(returns)*SQRT(days))-(NORMSDIST(confidenceinterval)*(STDEV.S(returns)*SQRT(days)))*portfoliovalue
```

Any help would be really excellent!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: break your formula into its parts and step through till you find the one that is giving the error.

Comment: I think it would help to share with us the original formula and perhaps some test data

Comment: So the original looks like:  =(AVERAGE(returns)*SQRT(days))-(NORMSDIST(confidenceinterval)*(STDEV.S(returns)*SQRT(days)))*portfoliovalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. First, your function name `VaR` conflicts with Excel's built-in `VAR` (variance) function. Second, there is no `Application.WorksheetFunction.SQRT` function; use VBA's `Sqr` instead. This should work:

```
Function ValueAtRisk(returns As Range, days, confidenceinterval, portfoliovalue)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        ValueAtRisk = (.Average(returns) * Sqr(days)) - (.NormSDist(confidenceinterval) * (.StDev_S(returns) * Sqr(days))) * portfoliovalue
    End With
End Function
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Good work, that's what I get for not dropping in test numbers myself!

Comment: The was exactly the issue!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a VBA function to return a value the format to do so is

```
'Function functionName(parameters As parameterType) As returnType
```

So yours (assuming the types I've chosen are correct) should resolve to:

```
Function VaR(returns As Range, days As Integer, confidenceinterval as Double, portfoliovalue As Double) As Double
```

---

Based on Scott's suggestion here is one way that you might choose to break up and "step through" the formula that you're working on. If in your code window you show `View > Locals Window` you can use <kbd>F8</kbd> to step through your code line by line you can see the values of `part1` and `part2` as they update from operation to operation.

```
Option Explicit

Function VaR(returns As Range, days As Integer, confidenceinterval As Double, portfoliovalue As Double) As Double

    Dim part1 As Double
    Dim part2 As Double

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        part1 = .Average(returns) * .SQRT(days)
        part2 = .NormSDist(confidenceinterval) * (.StDev_S(returns) * .SQRT(days))

        VaR = part1 - part2 * portfoliovalue
    End With

End Function
```

Since the test formula that you have to work with is

```
 =(AVERAGE(returns)*SQRT(days))-(NORMSDIST(confidenceinterval)*(STDEV.S(returns)*SQRT(days)))*portfoliovalue
```

I would recommend splitting each part up so that you can compare, for example, my `part1` to `=(AVERAGE(returns)*SQRT(days))` and so on

Comment: `Var` will not be a range, it will be a Double.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks Scott :)

Comment: Good idea to use `With Application.WorksheetFunction` to make it better readable!

Comment: But this will not fix the issue of the error.  there is a part of the formula that is returning an error and until the OP breaks up the formula into its parts and steps through the code we can only guess as the OP has not provided any values to test.

Comment: @ScottCraner I misread the question - when it said that the test formula works but the implementation does not - I mistook that to mean the vba math was correct but that the function was not returning for example. Shall I delete my answer?

Comment: That is up to you.  You currently have an upvote, I believe from Matt for the reason he provided.  But by it not actually addressing the problem or how to solve the problem it may lead to others down voting.  The ideal would be to show how to break up the formula into its parts, saving each to a different variable and instructions on how to step through the code to find the specific error.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the advice, I've added an option and explanation for Dan to use to troubleshoot his code

Comment: Brilliant this!  I'm new to VBA so the With Application.WorksheetFunction is awesome.  However, although now that the equation is finally returning a number, it is wayyyyy off what the test code is doing.  I've commented with the test code above.  What do you think it could be?

Comment: Also, when i do run the function, i get an error: user defined type not defined... but it doesnt seem to affect the VBA outputting a value

Comment: @Dan what line do you get the error on? Also, I would recommend breaking up the test code in the same fashion so that you can see what line(s) change things up. I added an example of this to my answer

Comment: I get it after hitting enter on the function wizard that pops up in the excel spreadsheer?  Is there a way to check VBA line by line like there is in R for example?

Comment: so i tried this: https://www.cimaware.com/expert-zone/compile-error-in-access-userdefined-type-not-defined and i still get an error...  I think the different outcome is because the VBA is skipping some of the user defined functions!  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: @Dan I mention debugging line by line in my answer :P  - however, xidgel has pretty likely uncovered why you're getting that error: excel can't tell your function from the built in variance function with the same name

Comment: xidegl covered the two major issues: the function name and the square root thing as well, so gonna give him the upcheck, but thank you very much @marcucciboy2 for your structuring the code cleanly!